# Gradle: compiling SNAPSHOT library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have this library I want to use, I can install one version, but the developer released a recent SNAPSHOT version, how can I compile it?

I've tried `compile 'com.(...):1.4.0-SNAPSHOT` without results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since SNAPSHOT is a Maven concept, it isn't treated as anything special in repository.

The best way to tell `Gradle` to check for updated version of a dependency is to flag the dependency as **changing**. `Gradle` will then check for updates every 24 hours, this can be configured using the *resolutionStrategy* DSL.

Override default module caching in Gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

Then, `latest.integration` will work with each SNAPSHOT:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('projGroup:projName:latest.integration') { changing = true }
}
```

For example in your case, *projGroup* is **com.prolificinteractive** and `projName` is **material-calendarview**.

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT') { changing = true }
}
```

## Edit:

Another problem is that bringing latest release on the *central* repository defined, this repository actually not contain the SNAPSHOT repository where the `-SNAPSHOT` was located. So that you should add to your `gradle repositories` section the repository URL to allow download the SNAPSHOT version uploaded.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}
```

Comment: this `compile 'projGroup:com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.3.0:latest.integration'` gives this error: `Error:(37, 0) Supplied String module notation 'projGroup:com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.3.0:latest.integration' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.`

Comment: Use `compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:latest.integration'`

Comment: It's compiling now, but still isn't the latest version, tehre are some methods missing

Comment: Problem is that is bringing latest release on  the "central" repo defined, and this repo actually not contain the snapshot repo where the "-SNAPSHOT" was located. Fot that if you force `compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT'` is throwing **Failing to resolve**

Comment: Look for my EDIT, I have resolved issue with repository.